# Modify a subset of html and append it with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will try to explain my question with a simpliefied version of the code I will leave out the ajax stuff.

What I want to do is retrieve a form via ajax modify some values and append it. This should be pretty easy but I just do not get it to work.

My code is...

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Test Jquery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var str = "<div><form><textarea></textarea></form></div>"
            $('a#action').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var result = str;
                var test = $("textarea",result).html("Hello world");

                console.log(test);
                console.log(result);
                $(".sections").append(result);
            });
        });
    </script>​​​​​​
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <a href="#" id="action">go action</a>
<div class="sections">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>#
```

The variable `str` should simulate the downloaded form from the server...
on click I want to change the

> value

of the `textarea` and insert `"Hello World"`...

What I would like to see is my str variable modified and appended to the sections div...

I can modify the textarea within a subset

```
$("textarea",result).html("Hello world");
```

But I do not know how to reflect it to the whole result...

Like I said this is a trivial abstraction so `str` can differ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var str = "<div><form><textarea></textarea></form></div>";
$('a#action').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var result = str;
  var $ajaxForm = $(str);
  $("textarea", $ajaxForm).val("Hello world");
  $ajaxForm.appendTo($(".sections"));
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAJHg/)**.

Note that `$("textarea",result).html("Hello world")` does not work in your example becasue `result` is just a string; it needs to be either a DOM element or a [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) object:

> **jQuery( selector [, context] )**
>
> selector - A string containing a selector expression
>
> **context** - A DOM
>   Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your result to the DOM first.

Then try

```
form.find("textarea").val("Hello world");
```